# Android: Is it possible to display a customizable dialog box activity which its content changes over a main activity after each method is performed?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

So I've been really conflicted about whether to use fragments or just stick to activities while designing my app. From what I read a lot of issues/crashes can occur due to using fragments and it's much harder to debug/maintain.

I have a main activity which on it a handful of methods are performed. Each method is triggered after the previous one is completed, and upon initiation of each activity a dialog box pops up with variable content.

I was wondering if it would be possible to perform this using one main activity containing the primary methods to be executed and one dialog activity for popups, keeping in mind the content of the dialog box is a variable. Is that possible to achieve this without using fragments?

Comment: `From what I read a lot of issues/crashes can occur due to using fragments and it's much harder to debug/maintain.` Where did you read that?! You can  a single Activity and multiple fragments. And also use dynamic DialogFragments.

Comment: @Rotwang One article that made sense to me was this one [link] (https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/advocating-against-android-fragments-81fd0b462c97#.by7z6v21o)

Comment: I'd call that article a mind-masturbation. Try Fragments, see how nice is to go with them and forget that B-movie.

Comment: @Rotwang Okay, I'm still new to this so I'm proceeding with caution :P Would it be easier if later on I decide to convert fragments into activities than the other way around?

Comment: It's different. Fragments live inside your Activity (well, DialogFragments can - not necessarily - be "detached") and you don't call them: You replace one with another one. Activities must be launched. But nowadays Fragments are the preferred way of building an app.

Comment: @Rotwang Thank you for your feedback & time sir.